# Complex LINQ paging algorithm

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

We have a list of projects that may or may not have a collection of subprojects. Our report needs to contain all the projects except those that are the parent project of a subproject.

I need to page this into pages of, say, 25 rows. But if subprojects appear on that page then ALL the subprojects of that project must appear on the same page. So more than 25 items may appear if necessary.

I've got as far as

```
var pagedProjects = db.Projects.Where(x => !x.SubProjects.Any()).Skip(
    (pageNo -1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
```

Obviously, this fails the second part of the requirements.

As a further pain in the arse, I need to have a pager control on the report. So I'll need to be able to calculate the total number of pages.

I could loop through the whole table of projects but the performance will suffer. Can anybody come up with a paged solution?

EDIT - I should probably mention that SubProjects joins back onto Projects via a selfreferencing foreign key so the whole lot, parent projects, subprojects and all, comes back as an `IQueryable<Project>`.

Comment: will subprojects contain subprojects?

Comment: Nope, one level of subprojects max.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try paging the parent projects instead, but only displaying its children.

```
var pagedParentProjects = db.Projects.Where(x => x.SubProjects.Any()).Skip(pageNo-1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
```

Then just loop through that project's sub projects when displaying the data.

```
@model IEnumerable<Project>

@foreach (Project project in Model)
{
    <div>
        @foreach (Project subProject in project.SubProjects)
        {
            <span>subProject.Name</span>
        }
    </div>
}
```

Now all subprojects with the same parent will be on the same page.

Comment: It's not that simple or I'd have cracked it already! Needs to show the parent project when there are no subprojects. Also, if there are, say two projects with 30 children, your code will show 60 rows. I'd need that to be split into two pages.

Comment: Well your first requirement is easy; you need to add a bit specifying if it's a parent and then use it in your where clause. `.Where(x => x.Parent)`. That will make it much easier to identify parents, whether they have sub-projects or not. Your second requirement I don't understand. I thought you couldn't page subprojects, you said they needed to be on the same page.

Comment: Scratch that, I think I get what you mean after thinking about it. How about, instead of trying to do complex paging, just create a tree node type interface where you get a list of parent projects and then could click a little plus sign to expand it and show its list of sub-projects. One option for this is here: http://weblogs.asp.net/mikebosch/archive/2008/11/25/hierarchical-treeview-with-asp-net-mvc-jquery.aspx

Comment: Pages should have a max of 25 rows unless more are necessary to show the siblings of those already on the page. A project with 30 children would therefore require the next project to be on a new page. So just paging on the parents doesn't solve the requirements.

Comment: I don't know why I assumed you are using MVC. What are you coding in? If it's web forms then tree node would be even simpler.

Comment: Because a list is a much better UI for the user. This is the data layer anyway, so assume I'm outputting to dead tree ;)

Comment: It's your project. I have just never had users have a problem with a tree view. Especially when they have a lot of data to sift through. I think a tree view is perfectly viable UI. But it's your call.

Comment: I have thought long and hard about how you'd structure LINQ in the way you want. I don't think you can. You need to do checking on all the projects included on your page to see how many children, how many parents are already included on the page, etc. A loops seems to be your option at this point. You may just have to suffer the performance hit.

Comment: The UI I've got is spot on and I don't want to compromise it just because the backend is a little more complex than normal. So unless anyone can prove us wrong I'm going to agree with you and build up a List<List<Project>> of pages in a loop. Thanks for your time anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I find its easier to deal with pagination by abstracting the concern away from the query.  Here is the source for the solution I use.  This will make your code much more straight-forward and transform all the paging logic into a single, simple call to `ToPagedList(int index, int pageSize)`.  I'm not 100% sure, but I believe I originally ganked this source from Rob Conery's Kona project (his blog is at http://blog.wekeroad.com/).

**The Helper Class**

```
public static class Pagination
{
    public static PagedList<T> ToPagedList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int index)
    {
        return new PagedList<T>(source.AsQueryable(), index, 10);
    }
    public static PagedList<T> ToPagedList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int index, int pageSize)
    {
        return new PagedList<T>(source.AsQueryable(), index, pageSize);
    }
    public static PagedList<T> ToPagedList<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, int index, int pageSize)
    {
        return new PagedList<T>(source, index, pageSize);
    }

    public static PagedList<T> ToPagedList<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, int index)
    {
        return new PagedList<T>(source, index, 10);
    }
}
```

**The Interfaces**

```
public interface IPagedList<T> : IList<T>, IPagedList
{
}
public interface IPagedList
{
    int TotalCount { get; set; }
    int TotalPages { get; set; }
    int PageIndex { get; set; }

    int PageSize { get; set; }

    bool IsPreviousPage { get; }

    bool IsNextPage { get; }
}
```

**The PagedList Implementation**

```
public class PagedList<T> : List<T>, IPagedList<T>
{
    public PagedList(IQueryable<T> source, int index, int pageSize)
    {
        int total = source.Count();
        this.TotalCount = total;
        this.TotalPages = total/pageSize;

        if (total%pageSize > 0)
            TotalPages++;

        this.PageSize = pageSize;
        this.PageIndex = index;
        this.AddRange(source.Skip(index*pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList());
    }

    public PagedList(IEnumerable<T> source, int total, int index, int pageSize)
    {
        this.TotalCount = total;
        this.TotalPages = total/pageSize;

        if (total%pageSize > 0)
            TotalPages++;


        this.PageSize = pageSize;
        this.PageIndex = index;
        this.AddRange(source);
    }

    #region IPagedList<T> Members

    public int TotalPages { get; set; }

    public int TotalCount { get; set; }

    public int PageIndex { get; set; }

    public int PageSize { get; set; }

    public bool IsPreviousPage
    {
        get { return (PageIndex > 0); }
    }

    public bool IsNextPage
    {
        get { return (PageIndex*PageSize) <= TotalCount; }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: That's pretty much an enterprised up version of what I've already got. It doesn't solve the problem I have in that pages now no longer have a consistent number of items.

Comment: Sorry, I initially only skimmed the question.  Your requirement is a bit confusing, but it sounds like you could get closer to where you need by using the Select(x=>new{Project = x,SubProjectCount=x.SubProjects.Count()});  It isn't clear to me from your wording exactly what you want, or I might be able to help a little bit more.  I think that if you use the solution that I provided above it will become evident that you are confusing your querying functionality with your paging functionality.  In order to write the query, you need to know What exactly it is that you want to get from your query

Comment: I really don't think you've understood the problem. Three screens of copypasta isn't going to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

What it sounds like to me is something like this:

```
    var pagedProjects = db.Projects.Skip((pageNo - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);

    var expandedPagedProjects = from p in pagedProjects
                                group p.subprojects by p into grp
                                select grp;
```

This would make expandedPagedProjects an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<Project, T>>` where T is the type of your subproject collection (for example, a `List<SubProject>`). So basically what you'd be doing is paging the projects into groups of 25, then expanding the subproject collections and grouping them in with their parent project. You can then display them however you wish, probably by looping through them with a nested `foreach`.

Comment: I have thought about this. This wouldn't stop some sub-projects from appearing on later pages.

Comment: Again, If there are, say two projects with 30 children, your code will show 60 rows. I'd need that to be split into two pages.

Comment: I'm sticking with a loop. Your logic is too complex for simple LINQ.

Comment: @sharepointmonkey: That's the behavior I thought you were looking for, actually. I think maybe I understand now...so if you're at 23 rows, and the next project has 12 subprojects, you want to show all 13 items but have a page break as soon as you've done that? Is that right?

Comment: @sharepointmonkey - On consideration, I think @Chevex is right: You're going to have to do this with a nested loop. Jon Skeet could probably work up some LINQ for this, but he can also divide by zero.

Comment: @Justin LOL that made me laugh.

Comment: Nearly - if a project has 12 subprojects you'd only show the 12 items. We only show the parent project if it has no subs. Does anyone know which tag summons Skeet?

Comment: @sharepointmonkey - Nah, you have to do a ritual. Do you have any goat's blood?

Comment: @sharepointmonkey - Having thought about this some more, I think `TakeWhile` could be the key. You could look into that, but it's going to be complex. I'll see if I can get it to work when I have the chance.

Comment: Cheers. I did think of that but I suspect that - if it is possible - it's just going to lead to some nasty hard to understand code that compiles into a loop anyway.